# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in admin\includes\html\database.class.php on line 45

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, apache, pdo

I tried getting the answer using other similar links to my question, but couldn't solve. Other questions refereed to have a PHP class, and use it. In my case I already have PHP Class, and I still get the same error.

I made this class as per explanation on the following link:
culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

In my case I'm using MS SQL.

Following is the code of database.class.php

```
class Database{
private $dbtype    = DB_TYPE;
private $host      = DB_HOST;
private $user      = DB_USER;
private $pass      = DB_PASS;
private $dbname    = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;

private $stmt;

public function __construct(){
    // Set DSN
    if ($this->dbtype == 'mysql') {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    }
    if ($this->dbtype == 'sqlsrv') {
        $dsn = 'sqlsrv:server=' . $this->host . ';Database=' . $this->dbname;
    }

    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query){
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
if (is_null($type)) {
    switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}
$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset(){
$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single(){
$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount(){
return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId(){
return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction(){
return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction(){
return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction(){
return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams(){
return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
}
}
```

Executing the following PHP code from other file (phppdo.php) will reflect the result as follows with Apache server:

First attempt executing phppdo.php will reflect the result.

Second attempt executing phppdo.php will reflect the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sattest\admin\includes\html\database.class.php on line 45**

Third attempt executing phppdo.php will crash the Apache server and restart Apache service.

And fourth attempt shows the result fine as per first attempt. This cycle repeats upon executing this file again and again for the testing purposes.

```
// Include database class
include('database.class.php');

// Define configuration
define("DB_TYPE", "sqlsrv"); // Values allowed: sqlsrv, mysql, sqlite
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "dbuser");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

$database = new Database();


$database->query('SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE incident_id = 1 ');

$database->execute();

$rows = $database->resultset();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Following are the Apache Error logs:

```
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:27.883145 2014] [core:warn] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:28.796237 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:28.796237 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:28.796237 2014] [core:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:28.799237 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4528
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:30.490406 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4528:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 03 09:35:36.041961 2014] [:error] [pid 4528:tid 1756] [client 127.0.0.1:63411] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/sattest/nzta-forms/admin/pdodb-tutorial.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:40.478404 2014] [:error] [pid 4528:tid 1716] [client 127.0.0.1:63418] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sattest\\nzta-forms\\admin\\includes\\html\\database.class.php on line 45
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:44.453802 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:45.002856 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:45.002856 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:45.002856 2014] [core:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:45.004857 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14276:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14456
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:46.597016 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14456:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Thanks a ton in advance for your help.
I really need to solve this as soon as possible.

~Satinder

Comment: Mate, that tutorial is silly... Why would you decorate PDO and remove features/functionalities in the new object? And the constructor is eating the exception. It logs to $this->error (which is private) but there's no method to access the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was going to comment but it got too big...

That tutorial is silly. First it wraps(decorates) the PDO class but removes most of the functionalities of the class. Also, in the constructor, the exception is caught and the message saved to a private variable that has no way of being accessed. Meaning you can't debug properly.

Anyways...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sattest\admin\includes\html\database.class.php on line 45

This means `$dbh` is not an object. Since `$dbh` is the PDO instance, there's a problem creating said object (maybe the script could not connect to the database, who knows, since the exception is being silenced).

So, do the following... In the database.class.php constructor replace this:

```
// Create a new PDO instanace
try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
}
// Catch any errors
catch(PDOException $e){
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

with this:

```
// Create a new PDO instanace
$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
```

and then post the exception you get. The exception should be self explanatory of what's happening.

Comment: I have discarded that database class, and using pdo code directly in the php files. Works fine. with no errors. Anyway, I'm still new to PHP and PDO thingy. Could you point to me somewhere where I can find 'how to' or how to make a class or function of PDO? Would like to just send a query and get the result stored in the variable, which I may process accordingly. Thanks a lot again!